# PHP regex to remove all spaces between dots

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i have got long string:

> $string = "This is string, when i need removed all whitespaces between
>   dots . I tried some examples, but without success ."

I tried to remove all whitespaces between dots, but without success.

Could somebody help me with right solution using php preg_replace?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you write desired output string?

Comment: Why don't you use `str_replace()` ?

Comment: you only need to replace the space before the dot, so `str_replace(' .', '.', $string)` should do, shouldn't it? Even if it was before and after, `' . '` would do

Comment: space between dots or space before dots?

Answer (score 4):

This will remove all whitespace before each dot.

```
preg_replace('/\s+\./', '.', $string);
```

`\s+\.` will look for one or more whitespace characters (spaces, tabs, newlines,...) followed by a dot. The next parameter specifies that the matched string will be replaced by a dot.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to learn regrx rather be dependent on a single line answer. I found a [Great and Easy Tutorial](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/regex/regex.php) online which would make regrx very easy for you. So that from next time you could create your own regular expressions rather being dependent on answers

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove spaces on either or both sides, you could try this.

```
preg_replace("/\s*\.\s*/", ".", $string);
```